# Type error using react-redux - configureStore

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I have the following program code. When running the application I get a TypeError and configureStore is flagged. What am I doing wrong?

> TypeError: baseReducer is not a function

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./userSlice";
import darkModeSlice from "./darkModeSlice";
import {
 persistStore,
 persistReducer,
 FLUSH,
 REHYDRATE,
 PAUSE,
 PERSIST,
 PURGE,
 REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";

import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
 key: "root",
 version: 1,
 storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 user: userReducer,
 mode: darkModeSlice,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, { rootReducer });

export const store = configureStore({
 reducer: persistedReducer,
 middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
   getDefaultMiddleware({
     serializableCheck: {
       ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
   }),
 });

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: You've a typo; `persistReducer` takes the root reducer function directly. Instead of `persistReducer(persistConfig, { rootReducer });` it should be `persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);`. See the [Basic Usage](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#basic-usage). Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the way you pass the `rootReducer` to the `persistReducer` function. You should pass the `rootReducer` directly instead of wrapping it in an object. Change the following line:

```js
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, { rootReducer });
```

to:

```js
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```